# using javascript & jquery to access header attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access an attribute of the head tag with a script that's placed within the head.

```
<head myattr="123">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert($("head").attr("myattr"));

    </script>
    ...
```

I cannot use includes or <%#"123%> or <%="123%> in .net "because of code execution order & page header dabinding. So i just set header attribute from code-behind.

Anyway the question is: is there something wrong with the way i'm approaching the problem?
Is it possible that when i call `alert($("head").attr("myattr"));` that i could get an `undefined` response?

I'm assuming that since `<head myattr="123">` happens before the `alert(...)` script is called, i won't get an `undefined` alert ... am i assuming wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention. Can't use `$(document).ready(...` it has to execute in the header.
I'm basically concerned if there are any unknowns such as compatibility issues etc that i'm not taking into considerations. Maybe some browsers will return undefined some not? maybe it can execute too early in some cases?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out, and see how it works ???

Comment: i does work... what i wan't to know is if it will work all the time... or if there are any compatability issues etc etc.

Comment: it will work everytime

Comment: If it works, it will keep on working as long as the head element is present and has a matching attribute! Contrary to popular belief, stuff does'nt just stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, since your script is after/within the head tag. However, `myattr` makes your HTML invalid.

Comment: thnx... what are the downsides of invalid html?

Comment: To be honest, not many in practice. Web browsers are very lenient to invalid/malformed HTML. Other user-agents/parsers might ignore your attribute, though. In this case you could make it valid very easily by prepending `data-` to your attribute name (assuming you're using the HTML5 doctype at the top).

Comment: awsome ty... i generally do use data-... wonder why it skipped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would get an undefined because as you said it is higher in the HTML than your script. However, it wouldn't hurt to wrap your call in a $(document).ready like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert($("head").attr("myattr"));
})
```

This should never return undefined as long as "myattr" is set.

Comment: thanks.... forgot to mention that it has to execute in the header... so $(document).ready( is a no go..

Comment: What do you mean "execute in the header"? Please elaborate.

Comment: it's for google analytics... i have to retrieve the attribute before the trackPageview is called...

Comment: Is there any way to delay the calling of trackPageview then trigger it by hand? Attempting to slice in code during load times doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: i could do that i suppose by calling trackpageview itself within a document.ready.  but it would also throw off analytics and some of the data that comes with it. such as page load time etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("head:first").attr("myattr"));
```

Comment: Are you expecting a page to have more than one head section ?

Comment: Your page shouldn't have multiple head tags... ever.

Comment: No, I'm expecting the selector to return an array and my page doesn't have many headers :D

Answer (score 0):

Make your `alert()` call after the DOM is loaded, like this:

```
$(function() {
     alert(...)
});
```